# Is there a way to precompile a hlsl file to a cso file without Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, shader, visual-studio-2019, hlsl

Is there any way to precompile a hlsl file to a cso file without Visual Studio? I checked on internet and i didn't find anything

Answer (score 3):

All Visual Studio is doing to create a `cso` is to use the FXC.EXE command-line tool to generate it, and use the `/Fo` option to output the 'compiled shader object' to a file.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dtools/dx-graphics-tools-fxc-using)